# How to self join a collection with SOLR and have another condition

Tags: solr

Refer to the following documentation: https://wiki.apache.org/solr/Join

According to the documentation the SOLR equivalent of this SQL query:

```
SELECT xxx, yyy
FROM collection1
WHERE outer_id IN (SELECT inner_id FROM collection1 where zzz = "vvv")
```

is this:

```
/solr/collection1/select ? fl=xxx,yyy & q={!join from=inner_id to=outer_id}zzz:vvv
```

Basically the SQL equivalent of what I'd like to do is:

```
SELECT xxx, yyy
FROM collection1
WHERE (aaa = "1" OR bbb = "2")
    OR outer_id IN (SELECT inner_id FROM collection1 where zzz = "vvv")
```

Is it possible to do this query in SOLR?

Answer (score 2):

Your query should be something like

`fl=xxx,yyy&q=(aaa:1 bbb:2) {!join from=inner_id to=outer_id}zzz:vvv`

Should be interpreted as `(aaa:1 OR bbb:2) OR {!join from=inner_id to=outer_id}zzz:vvv`